# SWIFT: UIImageView Photo Going Past Boundaries

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Can anybody tell me why my photos go beyond the boundary of UIImageView?

The pictures end up covering the buttons below it.

My code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Photo: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var QuestionLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!

@IBOutlet var LabelEnd: UILabel!

var CorrectAnswer = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Hide()


    Photo.layer.cornerRadius = self.Photo.frame.size.width / 10
    Photo.clipsToBounds = true
    Photo.layer.masksToBounds = true
    Photo.layer.borderWidth = 1
    Photo.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    Photo.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    Photo.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

    RandomQuestions()


}
```

[image]

[image]

I apologize for being such a novice, just learning how to code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's going beyond the boundary of your image view?

Try printing out the frame of your view to double check. Doesn't look like you have constraints set up from that screenshot - maybe your image view is sized to fit.

Comment: How would I print the frame to double check?  Sorry I'm uneducated in this area.  I just see the box for UIImageView so I assume that is the boundary, no?

Comment: If you haven't set up constraints to define the position/size, what you see in interface builder might not be what happens when you run the app. You can do `print(Photo.frame)` and `print(Photo.bounds)` to check the frame and bounds of your UIImageView.